# how to navigate to another page in wireframes using ninjamock

Tags: navigation, wireframe

how to navigate pages in Ninjamock.For example, I want to navigate to about us page on clicking about us option in menu from home page.

Answer (score 1):

You do this by setting a page link on a stencil:
1. Select the stencil in the footer which should navigate to About us page.
2. In the properties on the right side, click on "Page link" and select the About us page.
3. Now click Preview in the top panel and check that by clicking on the stencil you navigate to the desired page.